# Docker Compose Include option: (root) Additional property include is not allowed

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am trying to implement the `include` feature described in the Docker Compose documentation: https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/14-include/ but am receiving an error:

**(root) Additional property include is not allowed**

Has anyone come across this problem and/or know a fix for it?

PC Details:

- ProductName: macOS
- ProductVersion: 13.4.1
- BuildVersion: 22F82

Docker Details:

- Installed via Rancher Desktop
- Docker version 24.0.2-rd, build e63f5fa
- Docker Compose version v2.18.1

Commands:

- docker compose build
- docker compose up --build
- etc.

Example:

```
# compose.yml

version: '3.8'

include:
  - ./commmon/compose.yml

services:
  serviceA:
    build: .
    depends_on:
      - serviceB
```

And the other compose file exists with its defined serviceB

I have tried all of the syntax options (although with that error, it just doesn't accept 'include' as a root option). I tried `docker compose ...` as well as `docker-compose ...` with no difference.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to these [change notes](https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/), `include` was added in compose 2.20.

Comment: Ah, thank you. I didn't realize it was that new (and the docs don't provide a min version req).